# How to communicate between sibling components

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I am new to angular, please let me know if I am doing anything wrong or following a wrong approach.

I have a `foodDetails` component where on click of `buynow` button, food is pushed into an array.

`ShopDataService` is a common service used between `foodDetails` component and `headerComponent`, in header component i want to keep displaying the length of product array everytime when user click on buynow button in `foodDetails` component. So how to notify the header component when `buynow` is clicked in `foodDetails` component.

```ts
export class ShopDataService {
    products: any[];
    constructor() {
        this.products = [];
    }
    add(product: any) {
        this.products.push(product);
    }
    get() {
        return this.products;
    }
}
```

FoodDetails Component:

```ts
buynow(product){
    this.ShopDataService.add(product);
}
```

Here is a structure of my html container:

```html
<div class="container">
  <prac-header></prac-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The header component is prac-header, whereas foodDetail Component in router-outlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to communicate between sibling components (in my opinion) can be done by using service:

**service**

```
export class Service {
    private valueObs: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

    public setValue(value: string):void {
        this.valueObs.next(value);
    }

    public getValue():Observable<string> {
        return this.valueObs;
    }
}
```

**first component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component-one',
    template: `<button (click)="buttonClicked()">clicke me</button>`
})
export class ComponentOne {
    constructor(private service: Service){}

    public buttonClicked():void {
        this.service.setValue("someValue");
    }
}
```

**second component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component-two',
    template: `{{value | async}}`
})
export class ComponentTwo {
    public value: Observable<string>;
    constructor(private service: Service){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.value = this.service.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Maciej treder, your prompt reply helped me alot